Invariant Violation: "Dapit" has not been registered. This can happen if:Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder
The app working fine in android when I git pulled in mac and do npm i and pod install after that i am getting error:

nvariant Violation: new NativeEventEmitter() requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes
Invariant Violation: "Dapit" has not been registered. This can happen if:


Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

the file AppDelegate.mm here:
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"Dapit";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  return [self getBundleURL];
}

- (NSURL *)getBundleURL
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end


Package.JSON
{
  "name": "Dapit",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.22.3",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.17",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^11.0.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.16",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.25",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.3.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-app-auth": "^7.1.3",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-file-viewer": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.15.0",
    "react-native-gifted-charts": "^1.4.9",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-loader-kit": "^2.0.8",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-month-year-picker": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.7.4",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-radio-buttons-group": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0",
    "react-native-share": "^10.1.0",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.73.21",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.73.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.73.5",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.73.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}


If anyone got this type error and know the solution please reply.
